# gulp build for semantic ui very slow

Tags: laravel, gulp, semantic-ui

I've been searching around for days on this without much luck. I have Semantic UI installed via NPM with a Laravel install. I've modified my gulpfile.js in the root of my project to import the build and watch tasks for semantic-ui:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('./resources/assets/semantic/tasks/watch');
var build = require('./resources/assets/semantic/tasks/build');


// import task with a custom task name
gulp.task('watch-ui', 'Watch UI for Semantic UI', watch);
gulp.task('build-ui', 'Build UI for Semantic UI', build);

elixir(function(mix) {
    //mix.less('app.less');
    mix.browserify('main.js');

    // Start New
     mix
         .copy('resources/assets/semantic/dist/semantic.js', 'public/js/semantic.js')
         .copy('resources/assets/semantic/dist/semantic.css', 'public/css/semantic.css')
     ;
    // End New
});
```

This works, but the process is painfully slow:

```
[17:51:30] Starting 'package compressed css'...
[17:51:56] Created: resources/assets/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css
[17:51:56] Finished 'package compressed css' after 25 s
[17:51:56] Created: resources/assets/semantic/dist/semantic.css
[17:51:56] Finished 'package uncompressed css' after 26 s
[17:51:56] Finished 'build-css' after 3.45 min
```

Any suggestions for speeding up this process?

Here's my semantic.json in case it's needed:

```
{
  "base": "resources/assets/semantic",
  "paths": {
    "source": {
      "config": "src/theme.config",
      "definitions": "src/definitions/",
      "site": "src/site/",
      "themes": "src/themes/"
    },
    "output": {
      "packaged": "dist/",
      "uncompressed": "dist/components/",
      "compressed": "dist/components/",
      "themes": "dist/themes/"
    },
    "clean": "dist/"
  },
  "permission": false,
  "rtl": "No",
  "components": [
    "reset",
    "site",
    "button",
    "container",
    "divider",
    "flag",
    "header",
    "icon",
    "image",
    "input",
    "label",
    "list",
    "loader",
    "rail",
    "reveal",
    "segment",
    "step",
    "breadcrumb",
    "form",
    "grid",
    "menu",
    "message",
    "table",
    "ad",
    "card",
    "comment",
    "feed",
    "item",
    "statistic",
    "accordion",
    "checkbox",
    "dimmer",
    "dropdown",
    "embed",
    "modal",
    "nag",
    "popup",
    "progress",
    "rating",
    "search",
    "shape",
    "sidebar",
    "sticky",
    "tab",
    "transition",
    "api",
    "form",
    "state",
    "visibility"
  ],
  "version": "2.1.8"
}
```

Comment: could you please explain how you got working Laravel with Semantic-UI? I've been trying the last couple of days with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a copy of `/resources/assets/semantic/tasks/watch.js`to `/resources/assets/semantic/tasks/watch-dev.js` and remove all code related to compressed css, leaving only unCompressed tasks.
Then you update your elixir/gulp file:

```
var watchSemantic = require('./resources/assets/semantic/tasks/watch-dev');
require('./resources/assets/semantic/tasks/build');
elixir.extend('watchSemantic',watchSemantic);

elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.watchSemantic();

    /* ... */
});
```

If you need minified files, for production, do the inverse, leave compressed code and remove unCompressed.

This made my semantic-ui build and watch almost 50% faster, also, the way I'm loading the task works with Elixir `gulp watch`, so after the semantic.css is built, other Elixir tasks are reloaded.

Regarding to the 3:45 min build time, does not seem a problem of Elixir, or even gulp, it seems something related to hardware. You can test it by building a fresh **semantic-ui** standalone install, it shouldn't take more than 20 seconds. For reference, mine builds in 4s.

Comment: This is great information. Thank you. I'll go give this a try now.